# How to pass String Value between two fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am developing an application which consists of three `Fragment` under a single `Activity`:

1.Fragment(1) consist of Text-views.
2.Fragment(2) consist of Edit text.

Here is my problem:

When `TextView` is selected in fragment(1), that `TextView` value should be passed to the `EditText` present in fragment(2).

```
public class OrdersActivity extends Activity {

    private Bundle bundle;
    private ArrayList<String> eList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.orders);

        bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putStringArrayList("elist", eList);


        FragmentTransaction order = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        OrdersList orderList = new OrdersList();
        orderList.setArguments(bundle);
        order.add(R.id.frmOrderlist, orderList);
        order.commit();

        FragmentTransaction input = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        InputEdit inputEdit = new InputEdit();
        input.add(R.id.frmOrderinput, inputEdit);
        input.commit();

        FragmentTransaction quoteorder = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        QuoteFragment quotefragment = new QuoteFragment();
        quoteorder.add(R.id.frmSecondList, quotefragment);
        quoteorder.commit();


        FragmentTransaction quotechart = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ChartOrderFragment chartquote = new ChartOrderFragment();
        quotechart.add(R.id.frmOrderChart, chartquote);
        quotechart.commit();

    }
```

Comment: Pass it back to the activity, then the activity up to fragment 2

Comment: can u provide one example plz...

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7322619/android-correct-way-of-jumping-between-fragments

Answer (score 0):

The good approach is to use Activity as a dispatcher to communicate fragments each other.

1. Create a custom listener in Fragment1. Invoke a listener's method if text view is selected in fragment.
2. Create a method like *setCustomtext* in Fragment2 to update text.
3. Inside activity create a listener implementation and register it in Fragment1. This listener will be invoked when text changed and the invoke a *setCustomtext* method in Fragment2.

Please see the following link [Communicating with the Activity](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html#CommunicatingWithActivity)