# Android Fragment onActivityResult go to next fragment with data from previous fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

A have a fragment (Fragment A) which gets a selected photo from a user.  Once the user selects the photo in Fragment A I want to go to Fragment B and take the selected photo with me.  I am also using viewpager so the user can swipe between the fragments...I want the user to be able to choose the photo and in the onActivityResult in Fragment A go to or start Fragment B.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use a listener (ie. FragmentA.onFragmentBListener) to communicate between fragments.

In Fragment B, you will trigger an action, and listen for it in FragmentA (which can then act on the event, by starting, or doing anything).

Here is a good answer:
[Android: correct way of jumping between fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7322619/android-correct-way-of-jumping-between-fragments)

Comment: I want to thank you for the quick answer. Checking out the posted link I found my way to developer.android.com...I constantly forget that this should be the first place to look before asking a question! Thanks!